# Best option For Syncing Documents Directory Between Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I want to keep an apps `documents directory` that contains `sqlite` using `core data` files in sync across users' devices. The sqlite files are the only files in the apps documents directory and simply need to be common to all users' devices

I've tried zipping  up the sqlite files to send by email, which works with iTunes file sharing but is not suitable for my needs as it can expose the files to other users' devices.

I've tried using app groups to keep the directory common across devices http://blog.sam-oakley.co.uk/post/92323630293/sharing-core-data-between-app-and-extension-in-ios,

and

[Accessing Core Data SQL Database in iOS 8 Extension (Sharing Data Between App and Widget Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641768/accessing-core-data-sql-database-in-ios-8-extension-sharing-data-between-app-an)  but that simply did not share the directory across devices for me.

I've sent the file to parse, but pulling them down and reconfiguring the data was the problem there.

I've tried using iCloud and even the Apple engineer gave up on that one.

What I'm after is the simplicity of file sharing through iTunes (being able to replace the sqlite files) with  a bit more finesse and without the need to plug in the device.

Some considerations

1. The whole model can be synced in one go
2. Data does not need constant syncing facilities, a manual sync option would suffice.

Comment: For what it's worth, app groups are not supposed to share data across devices. Their purpose is to share data between different processes on the same device-- such as between an app and its app extension(s). No cross-device syncing is included.

Comment: Agreed, just trying everything to get this core data sync going inc reading some of your posts on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441909/using-core-data-icloud-and-cloudkit-for-syncing-and-backup-and-how-it-works-tog