# Use CoreData in today widget / extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6, today-extension

I'm building an app which also includes a today widget. The today widget should be able to read data from core data. I found a tutorial (http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/108082269360/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions) in the internet and did all the steps which were described. What do I have to do that I can use the fetched results controller in my today widget (I already implemented the fetched results controller code in my class)?

Comment: The same way as in any other table view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Core Data SQL Database in iOS 8 Extension (Sharing Data Between App and Widget Extension)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641768/accessing-core-data-sql-database-in-ios-8-extension-sharing-data-between-app-an)

Comment: No I get an error: `Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'` in this line of code: `var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate`

Comment: @Mundi No! We are experiencing the error: 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.   Thus, we can't get managedObjectContext as old way.